# Method Illuminate\Routing\Redirector::view does not exist

Tags: php, html, laravel, web, controller

tengo esta funcion en mi cart controller para direccionar a una ruta de "order detail" y no tengo idea por que no funciona y da el error de el titulo

```
    public function orderDetail()
{
    if( count(\Session::get('cart')) <=0 )
    {
        return redirect()->route('index');
    }
    $cart = \Session::get('cart');
    $total = $this->total();
    return redirect()->view('store.order-detail', compact('cart','total'));
}
```

así está en mi hoja de rutas

```
route::get('cart/order-detail','CartController@orderDetail')->middleware('auth')->name('order.detail');
```

la ocupe el comando "composer dumpautoload -o" pero no se solucionó

Comment: Usted es un amor de persona

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ o Daglas deberían considerar alguno publicar la solución y asi poderla calificar y marcar como aceptada, con lo cual la pregunta queda resuelta y ayudamos con la estadística en la etiqueta de Laravel por favor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes redireccionar a una url o a una ruta, pero no a una vista.

[Redireccionando a rutas nombradas](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/redirects#redirecting-named-routes)

> Cuando llama al helpr de redireccionamiento sin parámetros, se devuelve una instancia de `Illuminate\Routing\Redirector`, lo que le permite llamar a cualquier método en la instancia de `Redirector`. Por ejemplo, para generar una `RedirectResponse` a una ruta con nombre, puede usar el método `route`:

```
redirect()->route('order.detail');
```

---

[Vistas](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views#creating-views)

O tal vez quieras retornar una vista, en ese caso sería, dado que esta vista se almacena en `resources/views/store/order-detail`, podemos devolverla usando el helper de vista global de la siguiente manera:

```
return view('store.order-detail', compact('cart','total'));
```

Como puede ver, el primer argumento pasado al asistente de vista corresponde al nombre del archivo de vista en el directorio de `resources/views`.
El segundo argumento es una matriz de datos que deberían estar disponibles para la vista. En este caso, estamos pasando las variables `cart` y `total`, que se muestran en la vista usando la sintaxis de Blade.

Para el caso de esa vista, que está anidada dentro de un subdirectorio del directorio de `resources/views`, se puede utilizar la notación "punto". Como tu vista está almacenada en `resources/views/store/order-detail.blade.php`, puedes hacer referencia a ella de la siguiente manera:

```
view('store.order-detail')
```